# How to set more than one graphics effect on a QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt

I want to set **blur** and **opacity** effect for a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` but `setGraphicsEffect` just accepts one of them and remove the previously set effect. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is NO, if you need a combination of several effects you have to implement it yourself..